# How to quote Excel wildcards like * when filtering text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, wildcards

I have a spreadsheet where a number of entries are prefixed with a character also used as an Excel wildcard:

```
*.subdomain.example.com
*-uat.example.com
```

I'd like to use a text filter to find all the entries that begin with a `*` character:

[Custom AutoFilter interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFUc.png)

But this matches every cell, because `*` is an Excel wildcard.  I've also tried `'*` and `\*` to no avail.

How can I quote or otherwise enter the `*` character into an Excel filter and get a literal match to the asterisk character?

Comment: Try `~*` as the filter.

Comment: @ScottCraner Bingo, that does it.  Can you write that up as an answer and I'll Accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `~` to escape the `*` and let Excel know you want to search for the literal `*`:

```
~*
```

[image]

[image]

One note: This is the same with formulas that allow wildcards.

So if one wants to count the number of cells that have `*` any where in the string we need to use:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*~**")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to DATA tab.
2. Turn on Filter in Sort & Filter.
   An icon for filter will appear on the header row.
3. Click on the filter for the column you need to filter.
   A drop-down option will appear below the icon.
4. Click on Text Filters
5. Click "Begins With..."
6. An option window will appear and type in "*", without quotes > OK

... the column will now be filtered to all the cells containing "*" on its first character. You will also notice a check mark to the left of "Text Filters".

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, and it matches everything, not just entries with a leading asterisk.